# Selenium WebDriver Click() fails with IE9

Tags: selenium

(I've looked at many other similar posts on SO and have unfortunately not been able to solve this problem, so here goes...)

I'm using Selenium WebDriver (C# implementation, version 2.15) to drive a fairly simple webpage. The page contains a form with two < input >'s for username and password, and one < input > for submitting the form. I can successfully enter values for username and password, but the Click() call on the submit button appears to have no effect.

Per other recommendations, I have tried the following tricks, none of which has worked:

- Change window focus to currentWindowHandle
- Click on the element's parent, then on the element
- Add a long implicit wait
- Add a long explicit wait (by sleeping 20 seconds)
- Click a whole bunch of times on the element
- Use Submit() instead of Click()
- Send the keys "\n" to the element (Selenium reports this as an error)

Note that I have verified that the < input > button is indeed successfully found, so that doesn't seem to be a problem.

Also, note that I have verified the button does indeed work outside of Selenium-land. That is, I can browse to the site, enter login credentials, and click the submit button (and it works!).

Also, note that this problem is on IE. It does not occur for me with Chrome and FF7.

So that said, does anyone have any other ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is your site publicly available for test? Is your [IE zoom level](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Zoom-in-on-a-webpage) at 100%? It is a requirement for native click events to work from the documentation [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver)

> The browser zoom level must be set to 100% so that the native mouse
>   events can be set to the correct coordinates.

If this doesn't work then it seems a bug in webdriver. You should open an issue [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/list).

Having said this, you could probably go the Java script route in the meanwhile as a temporary solution. Something like,

```
driver.navigate().to("javascript:document.getElementById('yoursubmitbutton').click()");
```

Comment: How can I set the IE zoom level?

Comment: Yep, it is indeed the zoom level. Thanks! Although I really need a way to programmatically detect and/or set the zoom level. I can't have my tests fail for this all the time...

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it may be a problem with *where* the mouse click occurs. I tried using the Actions mechanism in Selenium to force a mouse-click with a bit of an offset. It successfully click the element:

```
new Actions(GuiOps.driver).MoveToElement(e).MoveByOffset(5,5).ClickAndHold().Release().Perform();
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem. I can't remember the post where I  found the resolution but I found that the following worked for me:

On a button:

```
  var navButton = driver.FindElement(By.Id("NavButton"));
 ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].fireEvent('onclick');", navButton);
```

Works every time.

I was also having problems sending the click event to a table row. Sometimes the .Click() would actually send the event to the row above (we have a horribly complicated table structure which has a hidden radio button within it which is also not clickable with Selenium). The above hack wouldn't work with cells that were accessible through a FindElement.

In the end the only thing that worked was to select the image within that row and send the click to that.

```
var img = driver.FindElement(By.Id("fim{4C3DE9FA-45B0-40E0-BD95-9EE0374EA38A}"));
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].fireEvent('onclick');", img);
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I see multiple solution here, but i thought I would share what worked for me in case anyone else out there needed a different approach. I had a similar problem, for me the solution was as simple as clicking using a different method

For example

```
btn.Sendkeys(Keys.Enter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `FindElement(By.CSSSelector("'CSSPath'"))`; If you have any CSS applied to the button, its more consistent alternatively write other multiple statements to find the element with alternative means such as ID,tag or so with the `WebDriverWait` Method

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to set Enable Native Events to "true" when you are running it on IE and if you want to run the same code in FF and Chrome,then you need to enable Native Events to "true" in those Browsers too.

You can do that when you are setting the Browser on which you wish to run.

Answer (score 0):

Try code -

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("btn")).sendkeys("\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.. 
WebElement hiddenWebElement =d.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
((JavascriptExecutor)d).executeScript("arguments[0].click()",hiddenWebElement);

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

```
@FindBy(id = "submit_action")
WebElement submitButton_;
...
public void clickSubmit() {

    if (driver_ instanceof InternetExplorerDriver) {
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver_).executeScript("arguments[0].fireEvent('onclick');", submitButton_);
    }
    else {
        submitButton_.click();
    }
}
```

As fireEvent is only supported by IE hence the alternative.

Answer (score -1):

One more possible workaround can be like repeating clicking like:

```
Btn.click();
Btn.click();
```

Because 1st click just set focus and 2nd one performs the real click. It worked for me.

Comment: The issue with this being that if you test with multiple browsers, the first click is going to perform an action, then the second click is going to throw an exception because it can't find the element.