# Click on Bar chart (text written on the chart ) doesnot work using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, charts, bar-chart

I am automating an application built on HTML5 using Selenium with Python XML source behind:

```
<g class="enteringBarsGroup" transform="translate(0, 3.42308)">
<rect id="idx9-2011" class="bar" style="fill: rgb(107, 158, 226); pointer-events:      auto;" width="321" name="2011" title="2011: 136" height="13.692307692307692" rx="3" pointer-events="none" opacity="0.8" isMouseOver="false">
<text class="labelshadow" x="0" dx="10" y="6.846153846153846" dominant-baseline="middle" pointer-events="none">2011</text>
<text class="label" x="0" dx="10" y="6.846153846153846" dominant-baseline="middle" pointer-events="none">2011</text>
</g>
```

The page has Bar graphs and Pie charts. When I click on a value of bar chart, the resulting values on the other charts change.

This is my test scenario. I am unable to click on the bar chart. I have tried the options below

```
 #self.browser.find_element_by_id("idx9-2011").click()
```

and

```
 #self.browser.find_element(BY.NAME,"2011").click()
```

Comment: What is the specific error that occurs when you run those commands?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should rule out [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8721253/1077279) (if you are using IE, you need to set zoom level to 100%).

Also, the other solutions on that page are worth trying too, e.g.,

```
self.browser.find_element_by_id("idx9-2011");
self.browser.execute_script("arguments[0].fireEvent('onclick');");
```

Sometimes it is not the `click()` which fires the event.  Have you tried, for instance issuing a mouse_down() followed by a mouse_up().  I'm not sure how to achieve this in Python, but you'd have to use the [advanced user interactions](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AdvancedUserInteractions).

In general with problems where Selenium has difficulty triggering a UI event, it is sometimes easier to find a solution using the Firefox Selenium IDE plugin and then transfer the solution to WebDriver.

Comment: Hi , @chris , The click doesnt work . I get a assertion error.

Comment: My Code looks like this : from selenium import webdriver #from selenium.webdriver.firefox import webdriver from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys import time import unittest from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By <code followed in SET UP class > try : self.browser.find_element_by_id("idx9-2011") self.browser.execute_script("arguments[0].fireEvent ('onclick');") except NoSuchElementException: assert 0, Error: u"null (WARNING:server didnot provide stacktrace info

Comment: Can anyone tell , if i need rerelook into PIP install , so that the click on the ID works ?